# java class.forClass() vs Class declaration

Tags: java, reflection

I have one class Student which is

```
package org.ahmed;

public class Student {

    public Student() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.out.println("Generated constructor");
    }

    static { // static block
        System.out.println("Hello world static");
    }

    { // insance block
        System.out.println("Hello world non static");
    }
}
```

and then

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("org.ahmed.Student"); // this line causing static block execution in Student class
        // Student s; // this line doesn't execute the static block.
    }
}
```

I understand by using `Class.forClass()` we can dynamically run any
class in runtime. But I have some question in other case regarding
static block.

If I use `Class.forClass("org.ahmed.Student")` in my `main` method, then it's
executing the static block of `Student`. But if I declare `Student s` in
`main` method its doesn't execute the static block. I thought
`Class.forClass("ClassName")` is same as declaring class with a variable
name.

Comment: Actually, it's `Class.forName()`, not `Class.forClass()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Class.forName("org.ahmed.Student")` you actually force the JVM to load the class and invoke its static blocks. You can read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Comment: So if I just declare the class reference with a variable name, the static executions are not guaranteed? like  Student s ?

Answer (score 3):

There's a distinction between *loading* a class ([JLS§5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3) and, I think, [JLS§5.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4)) and *initializing* a class ([JLS§5.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5)). By default, `Class.forName` does both, although there's [an override you can use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-boolean-java.lang.ClassLoader-) that lets you control whether to initialize the class.

Just declaring a `Student` variable doesn't initialize the class. In fact, even referring to `Student.class` doesn't initialize the class. You must do something to trigger initialization, such as something that uses the `new`, `getstatic`, `putstatic`, or `invokestatic` bytecode operations with the class (but see the link to §5.5 for details, there are other things that initialize the class).

So for instance, if you gave `Student` a public field:

```
public static String foo = "bar";
```

...and then in `Main.main` you did:

```
System.out.println(Student.foo);
```

...*that* would trigger initialization of the class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 1):

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-):

> Invoking `Class.forName(className)` method is
>   equivalent to: `Class.forName(className, true, currentLoader)`, where the second parameter specifies whether or not the class will be initialized.

So if you don't want to initialize the class, just call the method with initialize = false, e.g:

```
Class.forName("org.ahmed.Student", false, this.getClass().getClassLoader())}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Declaring the class references loads the class to JVM hence static block will be executed. i'm able to see static block execution on

```
Student s;
```

Example:

```
package com.snofty.test;
```

public class ClassLoading {

```
public ClassLoading(){
    System.out.println("in constructor");
}
static {
    System.out.println("in static block");
}

{
    System.out.println("in instance block");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassLoading classLoading;

}
```

}

```
Class.forName()
```

it is used to load the class dynamically by passing the class name
for example

```
public void loadClass(String className){
    Class.forName(className);
}
```

Comment: my bad.. i was executing the main method in same class of ClassLoaderTest class hence was able to see the static block execution..